# Blender texture video running faster in standalone

Tags: texturing, game-engine, video

I am trying to fix errors in the standalone I produced and I came along a strange one.

Although the video of the video texture is 1 minute and 40 seconds, in the standalone it completes (with lag spikes) in 30 seconds!!

What could be wrong?

Edit:  No errors in the console. The logic is an always sensor for the python controller that runs the script [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95274/video-texture-resolution-in-bge?noredirect=1#comment168318_95274). The video looks distorted, but it looks distorted both in blender where it runs the correct length and in the standalone. It's only a video in a plane, and the video is of .avi format.

Comment: _What could be wrong?_... any error in the console when you use blender embedded?, how is your logic?, how is your script?, how it look?, only play a video in a plane or there is something more?, also it maybe a codec problem?, what type of file is the video? and more...

Comment: Is it normal though that it should play the correct length while on Blender and at the exported executable to be shorter?
I'll put the info you asked by editing but I doubt it is any of that.

Comment: Try deleting the texture and setting new texture with the video path.

Comment: It isn't that. Just tried it on 4rth pc with better hardware than the one that went faster and it went normal. It is the hardware. But it is so strange that the low fps causes it to go faster with lag spikes. I can't explain it.